# How to find every occurrence of a target value in array and return a new array containing the indexes for these values? Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am working on a problem and am having a hard time getting it to output the right information.

What I am trying to do is find every occurrence of a target value and put it into a new array and output the indexes of the target values.  If no target value is found it returns an empty array.  `outputs {}`

Right now I am getting an error.

```
findAll(): 
[I@349b688e
[I@46ed5d9d
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

The outputs should be:

`outputs {0, 5}`

`outputs {}`

```
public class FindIndex(){
public FindIndex() {
int a[] = {7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7};

System.out.println("findAll(): ");
System.out.println(findAll(a, 7));
System.out.print(findAll(a, 2));
}

public int[] findAll(int a[], int num) {

    int indexNum = 0;
    int arrSize = 0;


    // find all occurrence of the target number
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] == num) {
            arrSize++;
        }
    }

    // create new array 
    int newArray[] = new int[arrSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] == num) {
            newArray[indexNum] = i;

        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

public void print(int a[]) {
    System.out.print("{");
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + ", ");
    }

    if(a.length > 0) {
        System.out.print(a[i]);
    }
    System.out.print("}\n");

}
}
```

Comment: Array objects do not have a custom `toString()` method. Use `Arrays.toString(yourArray);`. Don't forget to increment `indexNum`.

Comment: Where would I put Arrays.toString(yourArray); ?

Comment: Wherever you do `System.out.println(yourArray)` instead put `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never incrementing `indexNum`, it always remains at `0` and the array keeps on writing the values at this same index.

I think you should have this expression there:

```
newArray[indexNum++] = i;
```

Comment: I had it incrementing before and forgot to put in back in.  But it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

For your printing problem, what you're actually printing out ther are the addresses of the arrays returned, not the contents.

What you can do is the following:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findAll(a, 7)));
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(findAll(a, 2)));
```

This will give you the following output:

```
[5, 0]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `findAll(a, 2)` gets zero size `newArray` that's why you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You should check `if (arrSize > 0)` before doing array with indexes and access it.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with the code and got it to work but it is giving me added zeros in the new array.  The output of the top sould be 0, 5 How do I get ride of these added zeros?

```
int a[] = {7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7}; 
int array2[];

// print the occurrence of a target index value 
    System.out.println("findAll(): ");
    array2 = copy(findAll(a, 7));
    array2 = copy(findAll(a, 2));

public int[] findAll(int a[], int target) {

    int index;
    int found = 0;

   // find all occurrence of the target number
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] == target) {
            found = target;
            i++;
        } 
    } 

    // create new array 
    int newArray[] = new int[found];
    for(int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] == target) {
            newArray[i] = i;
            i++;
        }
    }
   return newArray;
} 

public int[] copy(int newArray[]) {
    System.out.print("{");
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < newArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (newArray.length == 0) {
            System.out.print( " " );
        } else {
            System.out.print(newArray[i] + ", ");
        }

    }


    System.out.print("}\n");
    return newArray;
 }


output:

findAll(): 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, }
{}
```

Comment: I was able to fix the problem.  Thanks